# Does there exist a commutative ring R such that SL_3(R) and SL_2(R) have the same finite subgroups?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, gr.group-theory

This question is inspired, of course, by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47407/does-sl-3r-embed-in-sl-2r/), and I don't know enough commutative algebra to know whether it's answered by silence dogood's answer to [this follow-up question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47710/does-s-4-inject-into-sl2-r-for-some-commutative-ring-r/47761#47761).  If the answer is "no," then the original problem will be solved.  If the answer is "yes," then the strategy that several people (including myself) were pursuing can't work.

Comment: Kevin Buzzard didn't think it was answered, last I heard. I don't think it's answered, but also don't know enough commutative algebra to meaningfully contribute any more.

Comment: You probably want R to have a unit. Otherwise take $R$ to be a nilpotent ring, say, with $xy=0$ for all $x,y$. Then $SL_3(R)=SL_2(R)=\emptyset$. Also finite subgroups are not the best testers for the embedding of $SL_3$ into $SL_2$. It is better to consider the maximal solvable or even nilpotent subgroups.

Comment: Yes, rings are unital here.  Mark, if you have better ideas about the original question I encourage you to post an answer there; I would love to see the original problem solved.

Comment: @Qiaochu: It is not an easy problem, it would certainly require more time than I can spend. But I would consider the Hirsh lengths of the maximal nilpotent subgroup in $SL_3$ and $SL_2$. That may fail, of course. Perhaps somebody else can do it. 